# Can a Turing machine or Push Down Automaton construct languages of type 3?

Tags: turing-machines, pushdown-automata, chomsky-hierarchy

I am not quite sure, whether automata can construct languages over their types. For example, a Push down automaton can construct a language of type 2 - does that mean that a PDA also can construct a language of type 3? The same for turing machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of languages of type $3$ is a proper subset of the of languages of type $2$. In other words, a language of type $3$ is also a language of type $2$.

If some automaton can recognize languages of type $2$, then it can also recognize languages of type $3$.